# Is there an equivalent expression in English to the Spanish word "sobremesa"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I was wondering what the equivalent English expression would be for the Spanish word "sobremesa"?
["**Sobremesa**"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y8JWgN2) refers to the chat or casual conversation that is held when a group of people have finished eating a given meal.

Comment: I wonder whether you might do better to ask on one of the English sites (there are two) since this is more about finding an English phrase than about the Spanish language itself. You can flag it to ask the moderators to migrate it if you agree. It is an interesting question and off-hand I cannot think of a word for it in English.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize this one was specifically for asking about Spanish stuff. I just flagged, now im waiting to see if it can be migrated to the English site.

Comment: As is now it is a bit poorly asked. Also, there are some posts in English.SE that ask the same: [Is there a name for the time after dinner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61012/37429) and [What's the English word for the Spanish “sobremesa”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/210316/37429). So I would check those and, in case the answers there are not satisfying you can edit it in here and we will migrate. Otherwise, chances are that the migration will be rejected.

Comment: Asking in English chat room I got [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49122019#49122019): _If a user translates the meaning of a word for us and meets other website requirements, then we will help them find a word with an equivalent meaning in English. We basically treat those like single-word-requests. We have a translation tag describing the requirements in greater detail. Think about it like this: You're searching the English vocabulary for a word and not the Spanish one, so you need somebody with an good English vocabulary, rather than a good Spanish one._

Comment: Please re-post your question over at ELU.